# Can we store the creation date of a folder (not file) using bash script?

Tags: bash, cygwin

Actually I’m a newbie at Bash and I’m learning with some hands on.. I used the following stat command:

```
find "$DIRECTORY"/ -exec stat \{} --printf="%w\n" \; | sort -n -r | head -n 1 > timestamp.txt
```

where DIRECTORY is any path say, c:/some/path . It contains a lot of folders. I need to extract the creation date of the latest created folder and store it in a variable for further use. Here I started by storing it in a txt file. But the script never completes. It stays stuck at the point it reaches this command line. Please help. I'm using cygwin. I had used --printf="%y\n" to extract last Modified date of the latest folder and it had worked fine.

Comment: General suggestion: don't use `c:/some/path` but instead `/cygdrive/c/some/path`

Comment: This could be helpful http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91200

Comment: @matzei , cygwin cannot find the path if I include /cygdrive in there.

Comment: @Inian , according to the link you posted, it is not possible to derive the created date of the folder using bas, is it? However, it also says, using "stat" and "%w", the birth date of the file is extracted. This is exactly what I tried, but the script got stuck.

Comment: @Kritzii: Feel free to check out other answers in the post, I guess support for it is only available in few file systems only like `ntfs-3g` or `ext4`

Comment: @Inian : I tried 'stat "$DIRECTORY" > timestamps.txt' . It prints all the data in there. For now, I guess all I can do is read this txt and extract the "Birth date" from it. Thanks for all your time :)

Comment: @Kritzii: Assuming your file-system supports providing the creation time, can you try the command you ran with a `-type d` option as `find "$DIRECTORY"/ -type d -exec stat \{} --printf="%w\n" \; ` and provide the output here or edit in original post and paste it?

Comment: @Kritzii: Please provide the output you have, I can help you get the `date` value from it

Comment: @Inian : Yes it did work! I got this as the output: '2016-05-20 12:49:17.222912000 +0530' . Now I need to extract the date part from here. Can you tell me, if I use this command in a folder which is a parent of several more folder layers, does this get applied to the lowest level of the folder structure?

Comment: @Kritzii: Is the `2016-05-20` the only part needed for you?

Comment: @Kritzii: Answer modified to suit the need. Please check it and upvote (and) accept the answer to mark it solved.

Comment: @Kritzii: Regarding your question to the application to sub-folders, YES it does. `find` by default applies the actions to all the sub-folders unless you manually restrict it to search within one or two sub-folder levels by specifying `-maxdepth` option. e.g. `-maxdepth 1` will not process sub-folders for more than the 1st level, i.e. the current folder. The answer is updated to extract the date alone. Kindly check the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do with a `-type d` option to include only the directories from the current folder, and as discussed in the comments section if you need the output from the `stat` in just `yyyy-mm-dd` format, use `awk` as below.

```
find "$DIRECTORY"/ -type d -exec stat \{} --printf="%w\n" \; | sort -n -r | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

To store the value in a `bash` variable:-

```
$ myvar=$(find "$DIRECTORY"/ -type d -exec stat \{} --printf="%w\n" \; | sort -n -r | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')

$ echo $myvar
2016-05-20
```

Comment: I used this but it produces the "last Modified date" of the current folder only. I need to find the "Created date" of the latest sub-folder present.

Answer (score 1):

The command is okay (save for escaped `\{}` which I believe is a mistake in the post). It only seems so that it never finishes, but given enough time, it'll finish.

#### Direct approach - getting the path

The main bottleneck lies in executing `stat` for each file. Spawning process under Cygwin is extremely slow, and executing one for each of possibly thousands of files is totally infeasible. The only way to circumvent this is *not* spawning processes like this.

That said, I see few areas for improvement:

- If you need only directories like the title of your post suggests, you can pass `-type d` to your `find` command to filter out any files.
- If you need only modification time (see what means directory modification time on Linux [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3620704/2016221), I guess this may be similar in Cygwin), you can use `find`'s built in facilities rather than `stat`'s like this:

  ```
  find "$DIRECTORY"/ -type d -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS %Tz %p\n' \
      | sort -nr \
      | head -n1 \
      | cut -f4 -d' '
  ```

  Example line before we cut the path with `cut` - most of stuff in `-printf` is used to format the date:

  ```
  2014-09-25 09:41:50.3907590000 +0200 ./software/sqldeveloper/dataminer/demos/obe
  ```

  After `cut`:

  ```
  ./software/sqldeveloper/dataminer/demos/obe
  ```

  It took 0.7s to scan 560 directories and 2300 files.
  The original command from your post took 28s without `-type d` trick, and 6s with `-type d` trick when ran on the same directory.
- Last but not least, if `$DIRECTORY` is empty, your command will prune whole directory tree, which will take massive amount of time.

#### Another approach - getting just the date

If you only need creation date of a subdirectory within a directory (e.g. not the path to the directory), you can probably just use `stat`:

```
stat --printf '%Y' "$DIRECTORY"/
```

I'm not sure whether this includes file creations as well, though.

#### Alternative approaches

Since getting the last created folder is clearly expensive, you could also either:

1. Save the directory name somewhere when creating said directory, or
2. Use naming convention such as `ddddyymm-name-of-directory` which doesn't require any extra syscalls - just `find -type d|...`.