# A makefile recipe runs every time even when target is more recent than dependency

Tags: makefile, npm

Makefile:

```
node_modules: package.json ## Run npm install
        @npm install
```

Why does `make node_modules` excecute the receipe `npm install` every time I run `make node_modules`?

I believe the recipe should not get executed if my file `package.json` is not more recent that the directory `node_modules`.

Comment: maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620684/directory-last-modified-date

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620684/directory-last-modified-date) that @IsmailBadawi provided in comments is the key here.

Make determines if a target is out of date [based on its last-modified time (mtime)](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax).  However, a directory is only considered to be modified when one of its direct children are added/removed/renamed (at least on Unix-like systems).

This is insufficient in your case.  Imagine the following sequence:

1. Run `make` for the first time.

   - Rule is not skipped.
   - `mtime(node_modules) > mtime(package.json)`.
2. Run `make` again.

   - Rule is skipped.
3. Change a dependency version in `package.json`.

   - `mtime(node_modules) < mtime(package.json)`.
4. Run `make` again.

   - Rule is not skipped.
   - Dependency is updated in `node_modules`.
   - But `mtime(node_modules)` is unaffected.
5. Run `make` again.

   - Rule is **not** skipped.
6. ... and so on forever ...

You can probably fix this by adding `touch -m node_modules` to your recipe.